# how to position these CSS elements without defining height and width

Tags: css, text, html

I am trying to create a little graphical box for a time element on a website. What I would like to have is something like this:

[image: final]

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <time class="entry-date" datetime="2011-09-16T09:59:48+00:00" pubdate="">
        <span class="date-day">16</span>
        <span class="date-month">Sep</span>
        <span class="date-year">2011</span>
    </time>
</div>
```

And this CSS so far:

```
.entry-meta {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    background: #aaa;
}

.date-day {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #444;
    float: left;
}

.date-month {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #666;
    float: left;
}

.date-year {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #888;  
    float:left; 
}
```

My problem is that I cannot achieve two things:

1. To align the text to the corners of the box and forget about the baseline. I would like to align 16 to the top left corner and cut it's box at the bottom right corner. I am looking for eliminating all the spacing pixels.
2. To move the year under the month, without specifying exact width and height properties. If I delete float: left then it goes under the day. What I would like to have is to move it right of the day and under the month. Do I need to create an other div or spand for the month + year?
3. Also, it seems that it doesn't matter if I remove `display: block` from the span CSS-es why is it?

Here is a jsFiddle I created:
http://jsfiddle.net/ESbqY/3/

[image: ver3]

An update one based on Kolink's suggestion:
http://jsfiddle.net/ESbqY/5/

[image: ver5]

Comment: What's the problem with defining dimensions?

Comment: Because the day is quite big and 29 is bigger than 1 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully customizable:

http://jsfiddle.net/5MMc9/8/

html:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <time class="entry-date" datetime="2011-09-16T09:59:48+00:00" pubdate="">
        <div class="date-day">16</div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="date-month">Sep</div>
        <div class="date-year">2011</div>
        </div>
    </time>
</div>
```

css:

```
.entry-meta {position: relative; font-family: Trebuchet MS;}
.container {float: left;}
.date-day {font-size: 70px; line-height: 55px; float: left; background: #fa7d7d;}
.date-month {font-size: 25px; line-height: 25px; background: #627cc6; padding: 0 0 5px 0;}
.date-year {font-size: 25px; line-height: 25px; background: #3ce320;}
```

Furthermore, you can add `display: inline-block;` to the month css if you want the div to be same width as text inside.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the last few hours I came up with the same solution, namely that its best to insert an other div. The line-height trick is really nice, I started using negative margins. BTW, why is position: relative there? I see no point for that.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the position. I just forgot to delete it when making tests. This was a nice little exercise. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
<span style="font-size: 2em;">16</span><span style="display: inline-block;">Sep<br />2011</span>
```

Will produce, more or less exactly, the result shown in the image.

Comment: I did the changes you recommend and here is a JSFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/ESbqY/5/ I think this way makes it really hard to position the month and the year relative to each other. Also, how can I get rid of the pixels around the texts because of the baseline align?

Comment: You don't appear to have made the changes I suggested... http://jsfiddle.net/2Xku7/ - is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the version to 5, now it's updated. I would like to align 16 to the top left corner and cut it's box at the bottom right corner. And also for the other elements.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cutting its box". What's wrong with the answer I posted that you need to complicate it?

Comment: I have updated the top image with color background to explain what I mean by "cutting its box" is it possible to do in CSS to cut a block level element to the dimensions of the text inside it?

Comment: Not really, because text needs to reserve space underneath in case you type a p or something that drops down. Similarly, it needs to reserve space above for taller characters.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as required:

```
time span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 2.5em;
}

time span.date-day {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
}

.entry-meta {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5MMc9/1/).

---

**Edited** to amend/use the colours from the question, and to remove the (possibly unwanted) margin between the `date-day` and the other `span` elements:

```
time span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

time span.date-day {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #444;
}

time span.date-month {
    background-color: #666;
}

time span.date-year {
    background-color: #888;
}

.entry-meta {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5MMc9/2/).

Comment: Thank you. I only have two problems with that. 1. What if its just a single digit instead of 16. For example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/5MMc9/3/ Also, is it possible in CSS to disregard the vertical spacing of the fonts? I updated the first sample with color for explanation. Also, feel free to use whatever HTML you prefer, the above sketch was just my idea.

Comment: Good point (I always [use leading zeroes](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5MMc9/4/) so I didn't think of that...otherwise I guess you're looking at a requirement of using [`min-width`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5MMc9/5/), unfortunately (I also added `text-align: center` to reduce the whitespace between the day-number and the month/year `span`s).